# Null References in API Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn Entity Framework Core by building a standard rest API using the code-first approach to generate the database. I'm getting null values in the JSON that is returned from my current `GET` endpoints and could use a hand in figuring out where I went wrong. The controllers are currently the default scaffolded controllers generated by Entity Framework Core.

The problem is that the JSON that is returned when I `GET` an install is:

```
{
    "installId": 1,
    "aadUser": "Mr. Doe",
    "progress": 0,
    "practice": null  //Shouldn't this reference a specific Practice?
}
```

This is a one to one relationship.

Models classes:

```
public class Install
{
    public long InstallId { get; set; }
    public string AADUser { get; set; }
    public int Progress { get; set; }

    public Practice Practice { get; set; }
}

public class Practice
{
    public long PracticeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Specialty { get; set; }

    public long InstallId { get; set; }
    public Install Install { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User_Access> Users_Access { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Billing> Billing { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

Context snippet:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        //Install
        modelBuilder.Entity<Install>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.InstallId);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Practice)
                .WithOne(p => p.Install)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            //Seed Database
            entity.HasData(new Install()
                {
                    InstallId = 1,
                    AADUser = "Mr. Doe",
                    Progress = 0
                 });
        });

        //Practice
        modelBuilder.Entity<Practice>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PracticeId);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Install)
                .WithOne(p => p.Practice)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

            //Seed Database
            entity.HasData(new Practice()
            {
                PracticeId = 1,
                Name = "Doe & Associates",
                Specialty = "Family Medicine",
                InstallId = 1
            });
        });
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Install>>> GetInstalls()
{
    return await _context.Installs.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: If it's possible for `Practice` to be null, shouldn't it be declared as nullable in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core doesnt automatically include related objects.

You need to Include it your query

```
await _context.Installs.Include(install => install.Practice).ToListAsync();
```

Link with more information: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data